# Software requires older version of currently installed package

Tags: linux

I'm trying to compile a program on linux and it's complaining that "qt 4.8.6 is not supported, use qt 4.2 or 4.3 instead". I'd just uninstall my current version and get the preferred one, however I don't know if I have other software that requires the current version of qt.

Is there a way to get this program to compile and run without uninstalling the current version of qt?

Also related question: Let's say there's some package called QT Helper that builds on QT. If that package is also used by the software that requires QT 4.3, do I need to get a version of QT Helper made for QT 4.3, or will it just interface with any QT4 version seamlessly? I guess that might just depend on the packages in question.

Comment: The first part of your question is off-topic and unanswerable. If the author of the program's build scripts have excluded recent versions, they presumably noticed some incompatibility that they didn't feel like fixing. You'd have to study the source code to get rid of that incompatibility, then remove the check from the build scripts.

Comment: The second part of your question depends on how this QT Helper program is written. If you want to know about a specific program that you're using, ask on [su] — [so] is about programming, not about using computers. If you have QT compatibility issues a program that you're coding, ask here.

Comment: The question was about how to deal with multiple version dependencies on a single system, not how to compile this software specifically... As per the second comment, the "QT Helper" program was hypothetical. It was another general question that for some reason you interpreted as some tech support question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use multiple versions of software.

Download Qt 4.3.0,

```
wget http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.3/qt-all-opensource-src-4.3.0.tar.gz
```

extract content,

```
tar zxfv qt-all-opensource-src-4.3.0.tar.gz
```

enter the extracted directory,

```
cd qt-all-opensource-src-4.3.0
```

configure,

```
./configure
```

build and install to directory

```
make
sudo make install
```

then you just need to add the `/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.3.0/bin/` (or where you installed it) to your PATH in .bashrc or similar, or just put an alias to the binary.